# Sending Bitcoin to 2 addresses in one transaction?

Tags: bitcoinj

I am new to Bitcoin network transactions understanding.

Can I send Bitcoin to one address and another amount to another address within the same bitcoin transaction?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Most bitcoin transactions have a second recipient address for [change](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Change) from the transaction.

However you can have multiple other recipients as well.  [Here is a link](https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-the-wallet#creating-multi-sends-and-other-contracts) to the official documentation explaining how to do so with bitcoinj.